# GET Request works on Postman but not in Python

Tags: python, c#, python-requests, postman, httpclient

I have a simple GET request with just 2 headers which works absolutely fine on postman.
But when i try the same with Curl or Python3.9 it does not work.
Can somebody please help me understand what's wrong with Python?

Here's the Curl - which works fine on postman - Response is 200

```
curl --location 'https://www.expedia.com/' \
--header 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
```

Here's the python3.9 code: - Response is 429

```
import requests

url = "https://www.expedia.com/"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'host':'www.expedia.com'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.status_code)
```

I have also tried the same with c# and it works like magic - Response 200

Comment: Check console in Postman and get entire Request.  Compare working and non working.  Usually in cases like this a default HTTP header is different.  Fix code and make headers exactly the same in working and non working request.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, I have checked the console and have used the same headers. In the postman i have limited the headers to host and user-agent and the get request works.
But, in python we get 429 response.

Comment: Error 429 is too many requests.  Python may be retrying.  Make sure Postman is closed when running Python.  A HTTP request is exactly the same in all applications.  The timeout for retrying may be to short in python.

Comment: There is no retry . It's just a single request

Comment: Then why 429?  Is there another app connecting from same machine?

Comment: Nope, no other app is connecting to the expedia

Comment: I would try using a sniffer to get actual request sent.  Python may be adding a header that is not in Postman.

Comment: Sure, i will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'User-Agent' header only:
In your Python code, you don't need to specify the 'host' header separately. The 'host' header is typically handled automatically by the requests library. Remove the 'host' header from your code:

```
headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
```

}

Use the '--location' flag equivalent:
The '--location' flag in cURL follows redirects automatically. In your Python code, you can use the allow_redirects parameter to achieve the same behavior:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
```

Try these adjustments in your Python code:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.expedia.com/"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)

print(response.status_code)
```

Comment: Hello @mian-adeel,  I have checked the console and have used the same headers. In the postman i have only host and user-agent and the get request works. 
I have also tried your suggestion to remove the host header, still have the same issue - Response code- 429

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `response.text`, you are being blocked

[image]

`urllib` seems to work though

```
import urllib.request as request

url = "https://www.expedia.com/"
response = request.urlopen(url)
print(response.status) # 200
```

Comment: exactly the point. The same request works on postman - Status 200, but not in python.
I have tried your above snippet, and i get 403 :(

Comment: @AshishVenkatBarad this is a different error, did you change anything in this code?

Comment: nope , i did not change anything. Used exactly the same code as above

Answer (score 0):

If one request works in Postman and the other doesn't in Python (or whatever), then the requests are obviously different (because HTTP is stateless). So I recommend to check what exactly you are sending and compare the requests. You can do that for example with [Responsler](https://www.responsler.com). Just choose a hostname and send a request both from Postman and from Python. You can see the differences directly.

Answer (score 0):

update your requests library. the last version is 2.31.0 .

Comment: I have tried updating to the latest version and still have the same issue